# requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session succeeds as scrips, fails from webserver

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I followed the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521486/tutorial-for-using-requests-oauth2), and created a working script that successfully authenticates with Oauth2 and pulls data from a web API. However, when this code runs in a celery task as part of a Django app it fails with a `invalid_client` error. The code snipit follows.

```
app_client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=config.CLIENT_ID)

headers = {
    "Host": "api.sitescout.com",
    "Authorization": config.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

token_params = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}

client = OAuth2Session(client_id=config.CLIENT_ID, client=app_client)
```

Is there something I should be doing differently to set up the connection from withing a running web application?

Comment: Does the `invalid_client` error come from the authorising party or from code on your machine? If the latter, dive into the source and check what conditions raise it; otherwise you could try logging the outgoing request bodies to a file and diff the working and non-working ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this [was an issue with `requests_oauthlib`](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/223). When I applied the patch [given here](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/211), the error was resolved. This is also fixed in the current master branch.