# How to write a python script to authenticate to Azure DevOps REST API and get the access token?

Tags: python, api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I authenticate to Azure DevOps REST API in a python script? 
I found that there are 2 methods :

- Using personal access token (PAT)
- Using OAuth 2.0

I am using the second method. Followed the steps in this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

I wrote this function to autherize to azure DevOps using OAuth 2.0:

```
def get_authenticated():

    client_id = < my client ID as a string >
    state = "user1"
    scope = "vso.graph_manage%20vso.identity_manage%20vso.profile_write%20vso.project_manage%20vso.tokenadministration%20vso.tokens"
    callback_URL = < Callback URL to my azure devops account >

    # Azure DevOps Services authorization endpoint
    Auth_URL = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" + client_id + "&response_type=Assertion&state=" + state + "&scope=" + scope + "&redirect_uri=" + callback_URL
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;api-version=1.0'}

    print(Auth_URL)

    response = requests.get(Auth_URL,headers = headers)
    print(response)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.headers['content-type'])

    response.raise_for_status()
```

But when calling this function, output I am getting is:

```
<Response [203]>
203
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The auth URL is correct because when I tried to access the same URL in a browser it successfully redirects to a form to enter azure user credentials.

The expected behavior of the script is, when the auth_url is requested, Azure DevOps Services should ask the user to authorize. I think that should be done by prompting for username&password in terminal/via a browser.

I am totally new to python scripting and REST APIs.
Can someone help me by pointing out the faults in my code or pointing to some samples?

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The http error 203 indicates that the returned metainformation is not a definitive set of the object from a server with a copy of the object, but is from a private overlaid web. In your code,you added `headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;api-version=1.0'}`, but in fact the content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can use some OAuth2 library for python to authenticate to Azure DevOps REST API, such as [OAuthLib](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib). It includes sevelral samples.

Also, you can refer to following topic, hope it is helpful for you.

[Tutorial for using requests_oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521486/tutorial-for-using-requests-oauth2)

Comment: I tried with the header you suggested. But the same error occurred.

Comment: can I pass personal access token (PAT) directly via header to access the azure-devops REST API?

Comment: @AnjanaDyna, you can not pass personal access token (PAT) directly via header to access the azure-devops REST API. If you want to use PAT authentication, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api).

Comment: I tried it. The authentication was successful with that method, for sure. But i was not able to use the python client api to create a new user in azure-devops. I posted it as a question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591886/how-to-add-a-user-to-azure-devops-using-its-python-client-api . Could you plaese help me?

Comment: You may try to remove the `headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;api-version=1.0'}`, using default instead.

Comment: Did you try with using the library OAuthLib? BTW, did you reigster your app?

Comment: I registered the app as described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops
. And used it's credentials as described in the question.

Comment: Is it okay to use ADAL library instead of OAuthLib?